# Memory leak using location manager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, cllocationmanager

I use the location manager with "didUpdateToLocation". I have a memory leak that I cannot explain:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *) oldLocation {

[newLocation retain];


 NSString *lCoordinates = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude];//Memory leak here!!!

[self setLocationCoordinates:lCoordinates];

[lCoordinates release];

NSString *lat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude];



[lm stopUpdatingLocation];


NSMutableString  *s = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@&radius=10&sensor=true&key=---MyKey---", lat];



NSLog(s);


id delegate = self;
AsyncConnectionController * connectionController = [[[AsyncConnectionController alloc] initWithDelegate:delegate
                                                                                           selSucceeded:@selector(currentLocationConnectionSucceeded:)
                                                                                              selFailed:@selector(currentLocationconnectionFailed:)] autorelease];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:s]; 

[connectionController startRequestForURL:url];

[lat release];
[s release];
[url release];

[newLocation release];
```

}

Thanks all for your help!!!

Comment: `locationCoordinates` is a property? And, you are releasing it in `dealloc` method?

Comment: First of all, you might consider to reformat your code sample, because it is difficult to read. How is your ivar `locationCoordinates` (and property/setter) defined?

Comment: It is: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *locationCoordinates;` . I do release it in dealloc. It has a "@synthesize", too

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reduce your code substantially just by using convenience methods (makes it more readable as well):

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *) oldLocation {

    NSString *lCoordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [self setLocationCoordinates:lCoordinates];

    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    [lm stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSString  *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@&radius=10&sensor=true&key=---MyKey---", lat];
    NSLog(s);

    AsyncConnectionController * connectionController = [[[AsyncConnectionController alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                                               selSucceeded:@selector(currentLocationConnectionSucceeded:)
                                                                                                  selFailed:@selector(currentLocationconnectionFailed:)] autorelease];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:s];
    [connectionController startRequestForURL:url];
}
```

OP specifies that `connectionController` is autorelease.

Comment: connectionController is "autorelease"